# Function that retrieves element from HList (while preserving its type)

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

I have this type which will be generated via shapeless:

```
type hlistt = STUDENT.type :: AUTO_LOANS.type :: HNil
```

Basically I have a bunch of case objects extending a trait so I managed to create a method which gives me instances of all case objects as an HList

Then using `import shapeless.ops.hlist.Last` and `init` I wrote a method to retrieve one of the nodes in the HList if the value is equal to the string "student":

```
def getLast(hl:hlistt) = {
  val last0=Last[hlistt]
  val la=last0(hl)

  if (la.value == "student") la
  else init(hl)
}
```

The issue is that if I call this method I will not get the correct node type  from the HList.

```
getLast(STUDENT :: AUTO_LOANS :: HNil)
```

The method works and returns the node but the type is off:

```
Product with Serializable = STUDENT :: HNil
```

**Do I need some Witness/Aux implicits to return the correct type?**

Comment: That's not the correct code to reproduce the result you describe. For one thing, `getLast()`, as posted, is not recursive.

Comment: @jwvh good point - I wrote this late at night (my time) and initially was thinking of a recursive fn. I did mean to wrap `init(hl)` into `getLast(init(hl))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`la` is of type `AUTO_LOANS.type`, `init(hl)` is of type `STUDENT.type :: HNil`, so

```
if (la.value == "student") la
else init(hl)
```

is of type `Any` (or `Product with Serializable`).

If you would like to return values of different types from different branches you need a `Poly`.

```
import shapeless.{Poly1, Witness}

object myPoly extends Poly1 {
  implicit def studentCase: Case.Aux[Witness.`"student"`.T, STUDENT.type] = 
    at(_ => STUDENT)
  implicit def autoLoansCase: Case.Aux[Witness.`"auto-loans"`.T, AUTO_LOANS.type] = 
    at(_ => AUTO_LOANS)
}

import shapeless.syntax.singleton._
println(
  myPoly("student".narrow)
) // STUDENT

println(
  myPoly("auto-loans".narrow)
) // AUTO_LOANS

// println(
//   myPoly("abc".narrow)
// )  // doesn't compile
```

This approach works if the string is known at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what you want to do. Given:

```
type hlistt = STUDENT.type :: AUTO_LOANS.type :: HNil
```

`Last[hlistt]` will resolve to `AUTO_LOANS.type` (your true if branch)
while `init` will resolve to `STUDENT :: HNil` (your false if branch)

the LUB (least upper bound) of these types will be `Product with Serializable` so that's why you see that.

If you want to check a runtime property of a member of the hlist you'll have to thread the appropriate typebounds and result types through by deriving them with the appropriate machinery. In this case that is already given by shapeless.

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/fdtn3cz/0

Is this what you wanted?

EDIT: 
I also just read

> I have this type which will be generated dynamically:

what do you exactly mean by "dynamically"? because unless you can specify some compile time properties, shapeless might not be the solution you're looking for.

Comment: You got very close to what I want. Do you know why I can't do: `if(last(hlist).value == "student") Some(last(hlist)) else getLastOrNone(init(hlist))` and adding a case for `HNil`. I get a type mismatch. I'm trying to traverse the HList and do a find node by value instead of by type.

Comment: the problem with that is that you won't know at compile time what the output type of your function is because it depends on runtime values. What is your motivation to use `HList`?

Comment: I want to preserve the types of `Car` and `Student` in your sample code. The actual problem I'm having is given a string "student" or "car" get the correct singleton ie Student or Car. I have type classes defined on these singleton types which is why I'm trying really hard to preserve types. I'm also looking into making some mapping of "car"->Car,"student"->Student so when I'm given a text I can use it as a key to get the appropriate type

Comment: well technically I guess you could formulate a function that goes from some hlist `A :: B :: C :: HNil` to `A :+: B :+: C :+: Unit :+: CNil` and finds the first match for some predicate poly-function or returns `Unit`. But because you base this off runtime values I don't think you can do it directly. what would the returntype of that function be? so it'd go more towards a solution as Dmytro said bellow.

Comment: Ya that's my roadblock: don't know what the type of that method would be :(

Comment: because there isn't one :D (I think) either you use witness which again gives you type -> type dependency or you widen the return type sufficiently e.g. using a coproduct or a sensible supertype.